# How to create TableViewRowAction

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view that has some information that is being loaded from a few arrays. I added some row actions that should display when you swipe the cell, but the actions are not loading and I'm not sure why. Can someone led me in the right direction?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {


        let shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Share", handler: {(action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in


            let shareButton = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Share using..", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

            let twitterAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Twitter", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
            let facebookAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Facebook", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

            shareButton.addAction(twitterAction)
            shareButton.addAction(facebookAction)
            shareButton.addAction(cancelAction)

            self.presentViewController(shareButton, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } )


        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete", handler: {(action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in


            self.restaurantNames.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.restaurantLocations.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.restaurantTypes.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.restaurantIsVisited.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.restaurantImages.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)



        })

        return [deleteAction,shareAction]

    }
```

Comment: Sure you set the `delegate` on your table view?

Comment: the UITableViewDelegate right? @PatrickLynch

Comment: That's the one.  Trips me up occasionally. :)

Comment: Yes I have it, but its still not work @PatrickLynch